# Soundcard quiet output

Tags: drivers, sound

I have an AKAI AMX controller which I use with the program "mixxx". I recently switched my laptop operating system from OSX to Ubuntu. I noticed that the audio output of the AMX controller is about half as loud as before. As far as I know, AKAI does not support Linux. Nevertheless, the sound card seems to work with alternative drivers. Is there an easy way to adjust the volume?

Comment: have you tried playing with `alsamixer` from command line?

Comment: Nice tip. I can make it a little louder now with alsamixer. But it is still quiet and if turn the volume to high it start to create noise. I have the impression, that there must be another way too.